# How do I manage Users and User Groups in Android / Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android but I am attempting to build an app that would allow a User to add other users to a Group . 
I have made a User and Group class, and I am trying to add a user to this group . . I am hoping that maybe someone here can point me in the right direction.

At the moment I have a User object and I am attempting to add this to a List within my Group object. Is this how users would be managed for an android app with user groups? 
I feel like there is something obvious I am missing!

I am using Firebase Realtime Database also and need to be able to store users added to a particular group so it is consistent on all users devices.

e.g. User 1 adds User 2 to Group A, both User1 and User 2 will see on their device that User 2 is in Group A

Code below:

Group Class

```
public class Group { 
public List<User> memberList = new List<User>() {....};

 public Group() { 
}
public Group(List<User> users) {
    this.memberList = users;
}

public void addMember(User member) {
     this.memberList.add(member);
}
public List<User> getMemberList() {
return memberList;
}
}
```

Main Class

```
User user = new User(uId, name);
Group group = new Group();
 group.addMember(user); 
       groupsDatabase.child("test_group").push().setValue(group.memberList.get(0));
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to have a Group object in your User class. When you create a new group, it can have a unique id when you push the group. Then the users in the group can simply have a list of groups that the belong to. Each item in that list can just be the id of the group, which would just be a string. The same goes for the group, there can be a list of ids that reference users.

Comment: Thanks sam_c, I will try this out. I've been trying to figure this out for ages now !